# Undefined variable: $row_cnt - php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a simple user_count method where I would like to simply show how many users have registered and activated their account. I know I have a total of 5 users, but it shows this when I am not debugging **We currenlty have 0 registered users.**, I don't have any php syntax errors but I get an error using ,

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL); 


function user_count($user_id)
{
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;
    $row_cnt = (int)$row_cnt;

    $db = new mysqli('localhost','admin','','secured_login');
        if($db->connect_errno){
            $connect_error = 'Sorry, we are experiencing connection problems.'; 
            die ($connect_error);
        }
        if($result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `active` = 1")){
            
            $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            return $row_cnt;    
        }
        
}
```

here is how I am calling the method or its result from a different file- footer.php

```
<?php printf("We currenlty have %d registered users.", $row_cnt);?>
```

on my browser I see the following error message

```
Notice: Undefined variable: row_cnt in /homepages/htdocs/includes/footer.php on line 31
We currenlty have 0 registered users.
```

I have the variable $row_cnt delared at the beginning of the method although the example from PHP manual did not declare it https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php.  I did this after I got the error message

would someone please help me point out what I am doing wrong.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the variable inside the function or import it from the outside by making it global.

```
 $row_cnt = (int)$row_cnt; // the right side is not defined
```

If it is already declared outside the function `user_count()` then use:

```
function user_count($user_id)
{
    global $row_cnt; //Here you make it global

    $user_id = (int)$user_id;
    $row_cnt = (int)$row_cnt;
...
```

If not then you can't declare a variable equal to itself, because itself has no value yet.

Try this:

```
function user_count($user_id)
{
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;
    $row_cnt = 0; //Initialize it to 0

    $db = new mysqli('localhost','admin','','secured_login');
        if($db->connect_errno){
            $connect_error = 'Sorry, we are experiencing connection problems.'; 
            die ($connect_error);
        }
        if($result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `active` = 1")){

            $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        }

       return $row_cnt; //Return 0 or another int.

}
```

Comment: Did you declare $row_cnt outside the function?

Comment: Simple to solve the issue instead of $row_cnt = (int)$row_cnt make: $row_cnt = 0; That will not give the error and $row_cnt will then get the value of mysqli_num_rows($result);

Comment: No, I did not not.  At first I did not declare it as per the sample from PHP manual http://us1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php.  Then  I declared it inside the function then I tried the recent suggestions

Comment: I changed the result position in your function, look how it is outside the conditional, in that way your function will always return a value.

Comment: I  must be going crazy.  Still same error!  I tried all  your suggestions :(

Comment: Thank you all It worked.  I had to change the way I was calling it from this --- <?php printf("We currenlty have %d registered users.", $row_cnt);?>       to this -----<?php echo user_count();?>

Comment: it really did not matter how I was declaring $row_cnt, matter of fact I removed it completely from the beginning of my method - NOT Declaring it as $row_cnt = 0; OR $row_cnt = (int)$row_cnt.  Thank you all again!

Comment: Eddy XP,  I have to update my findings/answer. so yes I had to   declare my $row_cnt as global.  This was the core solution to solving this problems.  Thank you! So when I called my method in my footer file, it should be bee like this:  <li>we currently have <?php 
               global $row_cnt;
               echo user_count($row_cnt);?> registered users</li>

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `$row_cnt = (int)$row_cnt`, which means `$row_cnt` needs to exist already, and it doesn't

Comment: I did not have that at the beginning of the method, I only added it after I received the error message thinking it was needed to be delcared first but result yield same error. if I remove it, I still get same error

Comment: You're trying to use it somewhere... I can't see what line 31 maps to but it means you're calling it before it was actually created

Answer (score 1):

you're setting $row_cnt to a casted type of itself, what at that time is undefined.  Just initialize it to zero.

Comment: I did that as per helion3's suggestion.  still receive same error